# Android Intent to launch radio application

Tags: android

I was trying to get the list of available radio FM applications installed on my device through an Intent, but I couldn't find any action to do that.

I was looking for something like "android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" which I'm using to find available music players, but for radio apps.

Is there any Intent to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may prove difficult.

Radio is not a part of the Android framework and is custom to manufacture devices. So raising the intent maybe a per device intent. Plus, this only takes into consideration that the manufacture actually set a custom intent receiver when they built the app.

Comment: Great. I think that makes sense, I just thought that maybe there was some abstract way to call al the radio apps and they could include an intent filter in case they were interested. Thanks very much.

Comment: You may want to check if HTC, Motorola and Samsung have a standard radio intent. If they do, then maybe you check for the intent availability. If the manufactures keep to a standard, you wouldn't have a very long list... but this doesn't take into consideration custom ROMs or smaller device makers.

Comment: Thanks again, I think maybe it'll be impossible to find all available radio apps unless I have a list of all of them and check against the installed packages, which is not a good solution either.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to start the application you can use Logcat to filter for the tag "ActivityManager" and you should be able to see the intent that is being used to fire that particular application. As mentioned above its OEM specific so you have to consider the possibility that it might not be there.

Once you have the intent, then you build an intent exactly as it appears and see if they allow applications to call it directly. From my experience most developers don't protect their activities very well, so calling a particular screen is pretty simple.