# adb command to turn on FM

Tags: android, adb, fm-radio

I looked up and down but did not come across anything.

Is there any ADB command or android way to to turn on FM in an android phone? Or i will have to create and app to do this?

Comment: define 'turn on the FM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [Activity Manager commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am) from adb

`adb shell am start -a <some intent>`

or

`adb shell am startservice -a <some intent>`

but you should read the question [Android Intent to launch radio application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611435/808940)

Unless you can find out what the intent is called then you may be completely stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need third party app. Read through manifest and try to figure out which intent to invoke. Sounds like work!!

Comment: you might be able to use logcat to see what intents are being launched, other than that there's PackageExplorer but you may be able to find more

Comment: Also https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept which is available on play at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&hl=en

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but isn't logcat used to log the errors? How can I use to it have available intent list?

Comment: All I meant was you might see the intent being triggered and logged by logcat ... it won't be able to give you a definitive list.